# Laravel Eloquent Relationships Empty and JSON

Tags: mysql, json, database, laravel, eloquent

I need to create models of existing tables, and return some of the models as JSON to my API.

It turns out that the last field returns NULL.

Table MCarga

```
-CargaId as PK
-CargaDescription
```

Table Movimientos

```
-MovimCodigo as PK
-MovimCargaId as FK
-MovimDescription
```

Model Movimientos

```
public function GetMovimientos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Movimientos','MovimCargaId','CargaId');
}
```

Model MCarga

```
public function GetMCarga()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MCarga','MovimCargaId','CargaId');
}
```

Another thing is that I need to get this as JSON objects.

Comment: Can we see your migrations?

Comment: I, this are existing tables, i didn't create the tables.

Comment: I'm assuming `MCarga` is parent table, if so `GetMCarga()` should return `hasMany()` and `GetMovimientos()` should return `belongsTo()`.